# Custom spacy NER model is stopping after testing for 2400 examples

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have trained a custon NER - Spacy model, when I am trying to test it on huge data, the testing is stopping after 2400 instances.
Below you can check the code.

```
import spacy
output_dir = "ner/"
nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
code = open('output.txt', 'w+')
count = 1

with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    test_text = line
    doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
    for ent in doc2.ents:
        code.write(str(test_text + '\n'))
        a = ent.label_, ent.text
        code.write(str(a) + '\n')
        code.write("---------------------------------------" + str(count) + "--- \n")
        print(test_text)
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)
        print("---------------------------------------" + str(count) + "--- \n")
        count +=1
```

Comment: Can I add any if loop to load the model again after 2400 examples completed. I tried but not able to make script.

Comment: When you say it stops, do you get an error? Are you sure you have more than 2400 examples?

Comment: Does it throw any error when it stops?